# Sharepoint Recurring Meeting Workspace Roll Over List Items

Tags: list, sharepoint, workspace, rollover

In Sharepoint 2010, how do you roll over list items from one meeting occurrence to the next?

Cheers,

FeemurK

Answer (score 0):

> foreach(SPListItem _item in SPList) {
>       if(_item["text"]=="123")
>       {
>         ////your code
>       } }

sorry for format i have some webbrowser errors, but it is how it works